# Connecting to a Cisco controller

Tags: wireless-networking, controller

I've setup a terminal according to [this guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/2500/quick/guide/ctr2504_q_s.html#wp37764),
but I still need an address to connect to, right?

How can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't need an IP. you only need a terminal emulator that use a serial connection

Choose one of this :http://www.techrepublic.com/article/access-the-cisco-cli-with-one-of-these-five-terminal-emulators/

and use a `Serial` connection

You have to know that the Console port doesn't enter on your Ethernet card, it needs a serial port emulator or usb converter to connect to your PC

Comment: I didn't realize it would only show up if I start the controller AFTER setting up and opening the terminal. Works now.